# Does popping a view controller call release on all of its properties?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, properties, uiviewcontroller, retain

I'm relatively new to IOS programming. I've finished a class where all the programming is done without ARC and I had a memory management problem that I was hoping could be clarified.

My situation is this: I have an app where a "parent" view controller holds on to another "child" view controller that it will push. So when this child view is pushed and then popped, it will not be deallocated because the parent view holds on to it. But even so, I think this child view still calls release on all of its properties when it is popped. I have (nonatomic, retain) properties inside it, and it must be calling release on those properties because those fields end up being deallocated and are null when the child view is popped, even though that child view controller itself still exists.

I thought that as long as I held onto the child view controller in the prior view controller, it would not release any of its properties even if it was popped, but I guess that's not the case. Am I correct about this? I couldn't find one, but is there a reference page that states everything that is called when a view is popped?

Comment: As Bergasms said, this shouldn't happen. It would help to see your code.

Comment: After reading Bergasms response I've figured out my error. It actually occurred due to me using retain properties to set an object from outside its owning class but using the variable to set that object from inside its owning class. Performing these sets in a specific manner while pushing and popping certain views caused the particular object to be deallocated. It's really hard for me to explain, but I definitely know this is the reason. This property had no business managing the object's memory in the first place so I've changed it to assign and the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be the case. When you pop a view controller, it will decrement the retain count of the child by one. But the child controller will not release its elementes until its dealloc method is called when its retain reaches zero. if you are correctly retaining it in the parent then it should not be dealloc'd.

Comment: Yes, I see now that you're right! After further investigation it appears that I'm accidentally deallocing objects by using retain properties to set an object from outside its owning class, but then setting that object via its variable from inside its owning class. Performing these sets in a specific way makes my object dealloc itself since the property set will call release on the old object. I had some very weird crashes that make a lot more sense now.